# Pandas checking for False value in Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a csv file that has something like:

```
col_a, col_b,isactive
a,b,true
c,d,false
```

I am trying to write all the rows that have true to one file and the ones that are false to one file. I am trying to understand how i can check for the "false" boolean flag in the dataframe.

```
# this works
df1 = pd.read_csv(all_users)
df_isActive=(df1[df1['isActive']])
df_isActive.to_csv('onlyactive.csv')

# this doesn't work below.
df_isNotActive=(df1[df1['isActive' == 'False']])
```

I am trying to figure out how to use "Not" inActive in a dataframe.

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to keep your code then change this `df_isNotActive=(df1[df1['isActive' == 'False']])` to `df_isNotActive=(df1[df1['isActive' ]== 'False'])` . You have to write the False after the column selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_isNotActive = (df1[~df1['isActive']])
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick way

```
df_isNotActive=df1.drop(df_isActive.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also try

```
m=df.isactive==False
df[m]
```

[image]